# Mount FUSE directory into CIFS share with correct permissions

Tags: permissions, root, cifs, fuse, shared-folders

I'm using Time Machine File System [(tmfs)](https://github.com/abique/tmfs), which is an extension of FUSE, to read the data on a backup drive and hopefully make accessible from a Windows machine:

Create a shared folder you can write to / read in both Linux and Windows -

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=<WinUser>,uid=<CentOSUser>,gid=wheel,ip=192.168.0.104 //hp1/Users/<WinUser>/p9230-stub /home/<CentOSUser>/p230-stub
```

Then funnel a FUSE directory into it, which you can read as a normal user in CentOS -

```
sudo tmfs /media/<CentOSUser>/p9230-Partn1/ /home/<CentOSUser>/p9230-stub/Partn1-viatmfs/ -ouid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g),allow_other
```

Although it mounts into my Windows share folder, and I can verify this with cd and ls, the folder won't appear when I'm inside Windows. The only difference I can see between small files I move to the shared folder myself and my fuse folder is that the latter is owned by root and the former by the normal CentOS user.

Is it possible to re-jig these commands so the FUSE folder gets picked up and shared?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the mount option `-o allow_other`.
This allows other users besides the owner of the fuse-process to use the fs (and thus the user of your smbd too).

If you haven't set `user_allow_other` in `/etc/fuse.conf` you won't be able to use that option unless you're root.

Comment: This helps in general, but [the question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/201769/13308) has the `allow_other` option in the sample command already.